# Kony service giving 1012 opstatus Request failed error and not giving response

Tags: temenos-quantum

I have a kony sample app where I am trying to do a build and the app has one web service in it for fetching categories of some product. I have the following code also that I wrote:

```
function GetCategories() {

var inputparam = {
    "appID": "bbuy",
    "serviceID": "GetCategories",
    "catId": "cat00000",
    "channel": "rc",
    "httpheaders": {}
};
kony.net.invokeServiceAsync("http://192.168.42.134/middleware/MWservlet",inputparam, serv_GetCategoriesCallback);

}
```

I am getting no response for this. Getting 1012 opstatus and the message is saying "Request failed" error.

Answer (score 0):

```
kony.net.invokeServiceAsync("http://192.168.42.134/middleware/MWservlet",inputparam, serv_GetCategoriesCallback);
```

In the above line, you have not given the port number in the MWservlet URL.(e.g. 8080) Give that and check.

Also, make sure all input params are being fed to the service and that they correspond to the exact naming convention followed in the service editor.

Comment: yes..port numnber solved my issue. there was also one extra space in inputParam in service editor in syudio. thanks,

Answer (score -1):

Visit : 
Find the below link. i hope it gives you a solution 
http://developer.kony.com/twiki/pub/Portal/Docs/API_Reference/Content/Network_APIs.htm#net.invo2

Check the mandatory and optional fields of Inputparam